# How to generate the PDF in CQ5.6.1 using page content in cq5

Tags: java, pdf-generation, aem

How to generate the PDF in CQ5.6.1 using page content.

A button in my site (genarate PDF) on click of the button i have to genarate the PDF file using the same page content.

Please let me know is there any out of the box PDF genarator in CQ or do i need to get the any linsenced product to genarate the PDF.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Adobe CQ is integrated with the [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/), a formatter able to create PDF files. [This tutorial](http://blogs.adobe.com/sunil/2013/04/29/creating-pdf-output-in-adobe-cq/) describes how to enable content rewriter providing PDF version of the content under the `.pdf` extension.

However, please keep in mind that this approach requires manually writing the XSLT transform file able to process your page (and every component on it) and output the [XSL-FO](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/) document.

Answer (score 1):

In a previous project (CQ 5.5) we used https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ to create PDF files.. worked pretty good!

Comment: did you install it as a bundle?

Comment: Sorry, I do not get it how did you accomplish the work with this tool, did you installed on the server? I thought of a dependency that you could include in your maven setup.

Answer (score 0):

I had used Phantomjs to create a a custom pdf from the cq5 pages. for example if you don  not want to display the right trail in the pdf or you want to disable the header footer. all this can be achieved with the help of phantomjs.
create a servlet which will execute a command at your server.

```
 phantomjs <custom.js> 'page_url' nameofthepdf.pdf
```

here custom.js will show or hide html content based on your need.

This will work for all pages irrespective of cq5 or any tool.